# UserControl Expand Vertically when Window is expanded

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface

I'm having trouble getting my UserControl to expand vertically when my window is expanded.

My UserControl currently sits inside a ItemsControl which is stretching correctly by setting the VerticalAlignment="Stretch" property on the ItemsControl.

I add the following UserControl to the ItemsControl:

```
<UserControl MinWidth="930">
     <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="730*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="400" />
               <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <DockPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Pink" LastChildFill="True">

              <ItemsControl Name="itemPanelOverview" Grid.Column="1" Background="Black" Margin="0"/>
         </DockPanel>
     </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The UserControl is called in an ItemsControl inside of a TabControl like so:

```
<TabItem>
     <TabItem.Header>
          HEADER EG
     </TabItem.Header>

     <ItemsControl Name="contentItems" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Blue">
          <Grid Height="35" Background="{DynamicResource GrayMenuGradient}" >
               <Image Source="..." Stretch="None" />
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding WelcomeMessage}" />
          </Grid>
    </ItemsControl>
</TabItem>
```

It appears that the ItemsControl (contentItems) is stretching as expected, as I can see the blue background stretching correctly.

I haven't set the height for this UserControl anywhere other than the Row Definitions. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Can you post the Xaml that surrounds your `UserControl`?  A control's size is often governed by its parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two aspects at play here:

The first is that when you have items in an `ItemsControl`, each item is actually inside an `ItemContainer`, so it is the container that you want to stretch.

You can design the container by declaring an `ItemContainerTemplate` for your `ItemsControl`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainertemplate.aspx

The second consideration is the `ItemsPanelTemplate`, which determines into what type of panel the items are placed. The ability of the items in the `ItemsControl` to fill up the available space is going to depend on the type of container as much as on the type of `ItemContainer`. For example, if you use a `StackPanel` for the `ItemsPanelTemplate`, it won't fill up available space because `StackPanel` grows and shrinks according to its contents. A `DockPanel` could potentially work, but only the last child would grow to fill available space. Perhaps a `UniformGrid` could do the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this correctly and I'm struggling to find an example online

Comment: I ended up changing the ItemsControl to just be a DockPanel which would stretch automatically, instead of trying to modify the itemcontainer template. Thanks for shining a light on where the issue was.